# TypeError: Cannot read property of 'channel_id' of null | Discord.js Webhook error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am working with webhooks right now. I am having my bot create on like this:

```
outputChannel.createWebhook(name1, {
            avatar: avatar
        }).then(webhook => {
            console.log(webhook)
            webhook.send(content).catch(console.error)
            
        })
```

All the variables are valid and it is creating the webhook. Only problem is when it gets to the `webhook.send(content)` it returns an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel_id' of null
    at /Users/me/Desktop/Bots/DiscordBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Webhook.js:162:81
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I have no idea how to fix this. When I `console.log(webhook)` it returns it just like it would if it was working.

Comment: Please include your reference of channel_id

Comment: According to the stack trace, it seems like it could be a Discord.js bug, but I can't find any reference to `channel_id` in [the source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/12.5.1/src/structures/Webhook.js#L162). Is there possibly more to the stack trace you haven't included?

Comment: No thats all was included